# Adding spacers in between the Outlook "Favorites" menu

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have a lot of email addresses, 3 personal addresses, 3 info boxes for various projects I run, 3 more inboxes for my job, I manage a box for my dad, etc.

This means that I have a huge list of inboxes, sent boxes, outgoing, spam, deleted, etc. To give myself easy access to the most often used folders (all inboxes and some sent boxes) I have added those folders to the "Favorites" menu at the top left.

I'd like to be able to add some sort of spacer in that "Favorites" menu at the top left. Just so I can differentiate between my peronal addresses, project addresses, work addresses and miscellaneous addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what I did was I took one of my lesser used email addresses and added a few new folders to that address. I named them all something along the lines of "-------------------------".

Then just drag one of those folders to the "Favorites" menu and voila, you have a spacer. The reason why I made multiple folders is because you can not place the same folder multiple times in the favorites menu, you have to create separate folders for that.

[image]

Comment: Pragmatic solution. I just wish Outlook would allow more than one "Favorites" folder, i.e. customize multiple such collapseable shortcuts... Maybe in the future.

Comment: This works for me too, albeit a bit ghetto.